# Difference between MSSQL and local windows time

Tags: sql-server, datetime

When I'm inquiry from MSSQL the query output is being shifted 2 hours forward against the local windows time.

MSSQL query time: 16:03
Local windows time: 14:03

Comment: Is your machine is in the same time zone as your MSSQL server? This could be the reason

Comment: When you write `Local windows time` - do you mean on the server hosting the SQLServer process, or on a different machine?

Comment: What function are you using to get the current datetime on SQL Server?